# Ler input do usuário via JavaScriptExecutor ou promt no Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, popup

Tenho 4 ambientes de teste.

Ao executar o script do Selenium, quero que o usuário informe logo após o navegador abrir, em qual ambiente o script deverá ser executado. Assim o script direcionará o teste ao ambiente correto.

Exemplo:

- Se digitar 1, o script direcionará a execução do teste em homologação.
- Se digitar 2, direcionará para produção, e assim por diante.

Já tenho o tratamento no script, mas não encontrei nenhuma forma de o Selenium ler o input do usuário.

É possível exibir um pop-up no JavaScriptExecutor que possua campo texto? Ou mesmo um prompt para ler este input do usuário?

`Console.WriteLine` e `Console.ReadLine` não funcionam no meu arquivo de Unit Test Project.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode chamar o comando `prompt`
Exemplo:

```
prompt("Digite o ambiente", "");
```

Mas aí você vai precisar de alguma forma capturar este retorno no JSExecutor, imagino que dê pra fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
String ambiente = (String) js.executeScript("prompt('Digite o ambiente', '');");
```